# Scrollbar hiding my Qframe widget in pyside2

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I am using QscrollArea in in my pyside chat demo application to display messages.

I added style sheet to make scrollbar transparent but, still it hiding my messages.

Below is my style sheet which are written for scrollbar.

```
QScrollBar:vertical {
    background-color:transparent;
    width: 8px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: #a0a0a0;
    min-height: 25px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

My msg ballon look like below when there is no scrollbar appear

[image]

and after scrollbar appear it look like below.

[image]

Comment: please, provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your margins on your widgets.